# Count pixel for black and white using OpenCV for Unity

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a mobile app to capture images of seedlings and calculate the plant growth by calculating the differences of white pixels for each image series. I already got how to change the threshold but I don't know how to count black and white pixels in the image. I'm using OpenCV for Unity plugin.

Basically this is all I have. Then I stuck on how to calculate the pixel number. By the way, can opencv for unity counts the pixels number because it's unlike the normal opencv?

```
public class thresholdpixel : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Texture2D imgTexture = TangkapGambar.MyTexture2;

        Mat imgMat = new Mat(imgTexture.height, imgTexture.width, CvType.CV_8UC1);

        Utils.texture2DToMat(imgTexture, imgMat);
        Debug.Log("imgMat.ToString() " + imgMat.ToString());


        Imgproc.threshold(imgMat, imgMat, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY | Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);


        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(imgMat.cols(), imgMat.rows(), TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
        Utils.matToTexture2D(imgMat, texture);

        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texture;
    }

    void countPixel()
    {

    }
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Wanna share any code to show the progress and where you stucked?

Comment: yeah, i already edit my question.